# getting scripts to run exclusively

Tags: bash, flock

I'm trying to get a bash script to run exclusively -- if another instance of the script is already running, then wait for the other instance to finish before starting the new one.   I found some references to `flock` which sounds like it should do what I need, but it doesn't seem to be working the way I expect.   I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

inst=$1
lock=/nobackup/julvr/locks/_tst.lk
exec 200>$lock
flock -x -w30 200 || { echo "$inst: failed flock" && exit 1; }
echo "$inst:got lock"
for i in {1..2}; do
        echo "$inst: $i"
        sleep  1
done
echo "$inst:done script";
```

And then I run

```
> flocktest.sh test1 & flocktest.sh test2
[1] 25213
test1:got lock
test1: 1
test2:got lock
test2: 1
test1: 2
test2: 2
test1:done script
test2:done script
[1]+  Done                    flocktest.sh test1
```

It seems both instances of flocktest are running in parallel...   When does `flock` release its lock?  How to make it keep the lock until the script is complete?

(An aside, if I do `flock -x -w 20 200`, then it complains `flock: 20: fcntl: Bad file descriptor`..., which seems odd, as the man page seems to imply I can add a `--w timeout` parameter before the lockfile...)

Comment: Works for me. Which OS are you running this on, and what fs is your lock file on?

Comment: The file is on a Linux box (2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64), and the file is on a mounted directory.

Comment: Ok, got it.   Apperently someone remapped the PATH, and it was grabbing a really old version of flock, which doesn't work the way I'd expect...

Answer (score 0):

flock seems to me very complicated.
Perhaps you can try this way.

```
cat script_unique.sh 
while test -n "$run_sh"
  do
    sleep 2
  done
  export run_sh="run_sh"
  sleep 2
  echo "$run_sh"
  sleep 4
  echo "$0 $1"
  run_sh=""
```

Comment: Thanks, but flock is indeed cleaner.   My issue was that I was using an older version of flock, with a different interface than what the man page described.  I'm closing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found my bug -- I was using a really old version of flock which had a different interface than the one described in the man page.   I updated to a new version of flock, and it worked.